# resource directory path could not be created Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-batch

I'm using the basic Microsoft quickstart for Azure Batch
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-quickstart

I've only filled the access keys with the correct ones but when running the tasks fails with 
"Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Common.BatchException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound''" at line 168 in 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-quickstart/blob/master/BatchDotnetQuickstart/Program.cs

On the portal the task is set as Completed with the error "The resource directory path could not be created"

The pool, the job and the inputs are created on the batch account and the storage account but I am not able to create those stdout.txt files

Pool allocation mode is Batch service, storage is LRS and hot.

Comment: You may want to post an issue directly on the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the said quickstart with the latest code and was able to build and run the solution without any errors. Got the expected logs in VS and output files created in the Azure portal as mentioned in the docs. Here is the screenshot for your reference:

[image: VS Output]

[image: Output files]

As a next step, just to be double sure, I'd like to suggest you to give it another try by re-running it by deleting the job from the previous run (do not delete the pool as the job completes in just a few seconds on a preconfigured pool) and examine the output. If the issue still persists, please create an issue with [quickstart](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-quickstart) repo itself as @fpark suggested above, so our Team can take a look and respond as needed. Thanks for reaching out.